# What is an overriden method in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop

This question is about the `SUPER` class.

When would an "overridden method" happens?

So say when I instantiate a class:

```
$object = Classname -> new (some => 'values');
```

Is that what you call an overridden method? the new method's overridden values?

If so then, why would I want to use that `SUPER` class?

I can just say:

```
$object = Classname -> new ();
```

I have the original method again. Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: No, this is totally not it - and any answer would basically repeat http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html.

Comment: What are you learning from? There might be a better book/tutorial/website etc for you. You shouldn't really get to needing 'SUPER::' until you're more familiar with basic OO concepts and subclassing - edit, oh and method arguments!

Comment: Consider taking a moment to sit down with a good book or tutorial. Close any tabs not containing said tutorial and read the stuff. Carefully. Take your time. Think about what your read. Read it again. Then try some code examples. Read again. Refactor. If it still doesn't work, consider asking on SO.

Comment: How many downvotes till I'm banned to ask?

Comment: You don't get banned for getting downvotes on a single question. Anyway, I think [perldoc perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) might be a good reading. There is an example of method overriding under the [Inheritance section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html#Inheritance). It's not what you think it is.

Comment: @BelmarkCaday - downvotes by themselves don't get people banned (though if you post 100 questions with -5 each, that may). They are a sign that people don't like the quality of your questions - basically, instead of asking interesting programming questions, you are asking people to explain the very basics of OOP 001 (not even 101) to you; **without seemingly doing any research yourself** (did you Google "subclasses/superclasses/OOP"?). And yes, getting too many downvotes may lead people to lose interest in answering your questions, even the more interesting ones (which you do have in there)

Comment: To repeat the very first comment I made to your first question I saw, you would strongly benefit by first reading up on OOP in general (a Wiki article, at least, or a good book), and then starting with a more fundamental Perl material (possibly even Learning Perl instead of Programming, plus at least some docs on perldoc as per the comment links on this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance describes a parent-child relationship. Everything the parents can do, the child class can too. E.g.

```
ParentA    ParentB
=======    =======
foo()      foo()
-------    bar()
     |     -------
     |   /
    Child
    =====
```

This UML diagram shows that `Child` inherits from `ParentA` and `ParentB`, e.g. via the code

```
package Child;
use parent "ParentA";
use parent "ParentB"
```

Now, `Child` has inherited the method `foo` from `ParentA` and `bar` from `ParentB`.

If `Child` defines a `foo` method itself, `Child->foo` would call this method, and *not* one of the methods of the parent classes. It is then said that the `foo` method is *overridden*.

#### Example

When subclassing, it is often useful to re-use the constructor of the parent. But sometimes, additional processing has to be done. In this case, a subclass wants to provide a different default argument:

Horse.pm

```
package Horse;
use strict; use warnings;

sub new {
  my ($class, %args) = @_;
  return bless {
    legs => 4,
    saddled => 0,
    %args,
  } => $class;
}

1;
```

SaddledHorse.pm

```
package SaddledHorse;
use strict; use warnings;

use parent 'Horse';

# This override the inherited “new”
sub new {
  my ($class, %args) = @_;
  # the “SUPER” pseudo-package points to the parent
  return $class->SUPER::new(%args, saddled => 1);
}

1;
```

Note how the `$class` is propagated to bless the reference into the correct class. The `SUPER` package is only available inside a package that defines an inheritance relationship, and is arguably broken. If you need `SUPER`, you usually want to use Moose, where a method that is explicitly said to override can call the super method with the `super` function.

#### Edit: A note on fully qualifed method names

If you call a method on a package/object, the correct method is resolved at runtime. If you look at the top of this answer to the inheritance diagram, you can see that `ParentB` defines `bar`. If we invoke the `bar` method on a `Child`, that method is looked for

1. in `Child`,
2. in `ParentA`, and
3. in `ParentB`, where it is found.

This is called “method resolution”, and is a tricky issue in itself.

If we pass a fully qualifed subroutine name as the method, no resolving happens, and the sub is called directly. E.g. `Child->foo` would resolve the method to `ParentA::foo`, so that call would be roughly equal to `ParentA::foo("Child")`. If hower we do

```
Child->ParentB::foo();
```

we get the effect of `ParentB::foo("Child")`. The syntax with the `->` is superfluous, but reminds us that we are kind of using a method on an object. Therefore, I preferred to write

```
$class->SUPER::new(%args, saddled => 1)
```

in the `SaddledHorse` example, even if this is only elaborate syntax for

```
# SUPER::new($class, %args, saddled => 1)  # pseudocode, won't actually run
```

which resolves to

```
Horse::new($class, %args, saddled => 1)
```

Comment: Before i read your answer, I would like to thank you for your effort on answering my silly questions here. I believe I'm in a stage called learning curve. Thank you thank you.

Comment: Can't I just say inside `saddledhorse.pm`   `Horse->new(%args,saddled=>1);`?

Comment: That's a very complicated example. Don't need multiple inheritance. `Base::foo` and `Child::foo` would suffice.

Comment: @BelmarkCaday Yes, the example is a bad one, but I wanted to show that a child class can have different defaults. A better, but more complex example could have involved GUI programming. `MyFrame` could inherit from `Frame` and e.g. have a default title and layout specified.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly that `SUPER` is made for those who are too lazy to look-up for the class name? or there are just too many class names to look up for? base class i mean

Comment: @BelmarkCaday Kind of. But that is like saying we don't need methods; we can always use the fully qualified name. Imagine the hierarchy `A <: B <: C` (where `<:` is “subclasses”). Assuming `A` and `C` define a method `foo`, `$a->SUPER::foo` and `$a->C::foo` resolve to the same method from `A`'s perspective. This changes if `B` too defines a `foo`. The `$a->C::foo` would break encapsulation, whereas `$a->SUPER::foo` would correctly call the method defined in `B`.

Comment: @amon - where is the notation "<:" from?

Comment: @DVK It has nothing to do with Perl. It is generally used as the *[subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) relation* in type theory. As a variant of this, Ruby uses `<` to denote inheritance in class definitions. The subtyping relation is reflexive and transitive (this does not hold with duck typing). In most type systems, it is antisymmetric, thus imposing a partial order over all types.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have more context? It's probably referring to a method overridden in a subclass.

e.g.

```
use feature 'say';

package A;

sub foo {
   say "A";
}

package B;
use base 'A';

# this is overriding 'foo' in A.
sub foo {
   my $class = shift;
   $class->SUPER::foo(); # calls A->foo(), but this is optional
   say "B";
}

B->foo(); # prints "A" then "B"
```

The calling of SUPER::foo is optional - the method can just override `foo` and replace it's behaviour or augment it, either by doing work before SUPER::foo or after.

More modern OO perl, (e.g. using Moose, Moo, etc) makes this more readable - with calls to features such as 'override', 'before', 'after', 'around' etc to alter inherited methods